# How to compile Cocos2d-X with Marmalade?

Tags: compilation, cross-platform, cocos2d-x, marmalade

Does any body know a tutorial, or a three simple step in order to compile the code the I wrote with Cocos2d-x with Marmalade?

I want to take the code I already compiled and used in Cocos2d-X, insert into a marmalade project, and compile.
In lots of places is written as easy, but I have difficult with this.

**I'll really appreciate if someone has some easy step to follow: "Maramalade + cocos2d-x for dummies style :)  "**

Thanks, 
Adrian.

Comment: Silly question but considering you
> "have no experience with C++ and with Visual Studio" Why are you even considering Marmalade?

Answer (score 2):

I think [this post](http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/node/3873) on `Marmalade` forum may help you.

Comment: I tried, but is not clear exactly what to do. I have no experience with C++ and with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version include project mkb for helloworld and tests follow them.