# Newbie to 2d/3d Games - Need Clarification on game Engine Cocos2d-x and Marmalade

Tags: lua, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, marmalade, cocos2d-x-2.x

After many research online i rounded up on cocos2d-x 3 and marmalade for my game development learning and might be future publishing :)

Wen I was about to fix on one particular engine, i went though some questions in stackoverflow regarding both engine together..

Ex:
[How to compile Cocos2d-X with Marmalade?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279374/how-to-compile-cocos2d-x-with-marmalade?rq=1)

[Cocos2d-x and Marmalade - Troubles with CCCallFuncO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325347/cocos2d-x-and-marmalade-troubles-with-cccallfunco?rq=1)

[Marmalade: better using Cocos2d-x v.2 or Cocos2d-x v.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13562403/marmalade-better-using-cocos2d-x-v-2-or-cocos2d-x-v-1?rq=1)

My doubt is, why these both are used together for game/app develoment.

I am new to c++ /Lua.. but very interested to learn.

I am yet to fix on my final engine for my learning.. either cocos2d-x(difficult for a newbie, but yeah i am ready to do the hardwork) or marmalade(paid, and has been used for Cut the Rope)

Q 1. Can anyone help me understand why developers used  both these engines together.? Are there any advantages..?

Q 2. Can we create good apps as well with these 2 engines, becoz majority of online sites point for games and its advantages on games etc...?

Q 3. Even after reading a lot of comparison about cocos2d-x and marmalade, still i am confused which to choose, since i m worried about the learning curve. Can anyone advice on what i shud choose as a newbie to c++ / lua?

Note: Even though i wanted to try Unity2D/3D, I cant pay$1500 + $1500(ios) + $1500(android) .. Not that much Cash to invest now. :)

Need your valuable help on this .

Comment: There are no answers to these questions that do no constitute someones opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Marmalade already has Cocos2D-x integrated - look for "Quick". Marmalade SDK consists of 4 separate and "completely" different APIs - C++, Quick (Lua/Cocos/Box2D), Juice (porting iOS to Android), Web (PhoneGap).

Here is ad blurb https://www.madewithmarmalade.com/products/quick, here is documentation http://docs.madewithmarmalade.com/display/MD/Marmalade+Quick.

What they have done in "Quick" is to integrate for you a Lua interpreter + Cocos2D-x library (sprite animation) + Box2D (physics engine). It quite easy to start with that. Use the free license and then figure out if need more (difference is support/ad splash on load/exotic platforms/)

Comment: thanks for your response.. Is there supporting tools like IDE for animation creator, level creator etc for using with marmalade.?